# Inserir "marca D'Água" em vídeo no momento do upload

Tags: php

No momento faço upload simples de videos com php básico. Não uso código muito complexo, fico só no básico! E esse básico é praticamente o seguinte:

```
$mp4    = $_FILES['mp4'];
$mpname = $mp4['mpname'];
$mptmp  = $mp4['tmp_name'];
$mpsize = $mp4['size'];
$format ="mp4"; 
$mppasta        ="../videos/";
$mppermiti  =array('mp4');
```

Após verificar tudo faço o upload final

```
$upload = move_uploaded_file($tmp, $mppasta.'/'.$mpname);}; //Faz o upload do video para o servidor
```

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de inserir marca D'Água no vídeo no momento do upload

Answer (score 2):

Dá uma verificada nessa ferramenta: https://www.ffmpeg.org/

e para rodar em php ficaria algo assim:

```
exec('ffmpeg -i meuvideo.mp4 -i marcadagua.png -filter_complex overlay saida.mp4');
```